# A python for loop using shutil.copy2 doesn't copy everything in OS X

Tags: python, file, shutil

When `copy2` is in a `for` loop iterating over multiple folders, it doesn't copy everything. But, when I execute it on a single folder, everything works fine and everything within the folder is copied.

Here is the snippet of code I have been testing with

```
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(presetsPath):
  for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.adg'):
    name = filename.replace(extensionAbleton, '')
    index = int(name.split(' ')[-1])-10000
    name = presetsSorted[index]
    #print index, name, presets[name]['bankName']
    bankName = presets[name]['bankName'].replace("/", " ")
    category = presets[name]['categoryName'].replace("/", " ")
    targetRoot = os.path.join(outputPath, instrument, bankName, category)
    #print "root", targetRoot

    fullPath = os.path.join(root, filename)

    targetName = presets[name]['name']+extensionAbleton
    targetFullPath = os.path.join(targetRoot, targetName)
    targetFullPath = targetFullPath.replace("//", "/")
    logging.debug("name="+str(name)+" index="+str(index)+" category="+presets[name]['categoryName']+" path="+targetName)

    #print targetFullPath
    if not os.path.exists(targetRoot):
        os.makedirs(targetRoot)
    shutil.copy2(fullPath, targetFullPath)
```

I don't understand why copying a single folder works, but using the snippet above does not copy all of the files. Does this have anything to do with the queue? Is there a smarter way that I could go about doing this copy?

Comment: What do you mean by *it doesn't copy everything*? What is missing? Have you tried adding print statements to see what paths you are giving to `shutil.copy2()`?

Comment: Also, why not use `shutil.copytree()` here?

Comment: U believe that copytree copies everything within a folder is that right?  if so I cannot use it because the code determines what each file name is supposed be called.

Comment: random files are missing, despite the print statements showing everything should be there.

Comment: Yes, I see you are transforming the file names. I didn't analyse your code there, but is it at all possible you generate *duplicate filenames*? That'd be a cause of files overwriting data already copied across.